# How to pass macro function as parameter

Tags: c

I have a macro function define and implement like this:

```
#define TASK(k) void task_##k(void)
TASK(T1){ // expand to void task_T1(void)
 //.....do something
}
```

I call `task_T1()` in main function can work, but when I assign `task_T1` to `(void)(*fptr)(void)` would get wrong.

I wondering are there any possible to pass task_T1 as function pointer into another function?

Comment: No. I don't think so. When you're calling task_T1() you know the name already in the first place. Just use functions with different names which calls a common function.

Comment: There is nothing special about using a macro to form a function declaration that would prevent a pointer to the function being obtained or being used in any way that is valid for a pointer of its type.  Please present a [mre] if you want to know about why your particular attempts are not working as you want.

Answer (score 1):

some options

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TASK(k) task_##k

void TASK(T1)(void){ // expand to void task_T1
printf("T1\n");
}

#define TASKNAME(k) task_##k
#define TASK1(k) void TASKNAME(k)(void)
#define TASKCALL(k) TASKNAME(k)()

TASK1(T2)
{
    printf("T2\n");
}

void (*ptr)(void) = TASK(T1);
void (*ptr1)(void) = TASKNAME(T2);


int main(void)
{
    TASK(T1)();
    ptr();
    TASKNAME(T2)();
    TASKCALL(T2);
    ptr1();
}
```